# Making a furniture layout tool, need some advice

Tags: php, javascript, raphael

I am making a web application that will mostly take place client side and have the data processed and stored on the server side (PHP/MySQL). The app lets you add different pieces of furniture to a room. These pieces of furniture are going to represented mostly by simple shapes (rectangle, square, etc...) except for a couple unique ones like a "L" shape and a "U" shape (no curve, all straight edges). I need to be able to calculate the square footage of any of these pieces depending on what dimensions the user puts in. What is the best way to store the "formulas" with each piece?

The other part is I plan to have a drag and drop type interface where the user can place the furniture in a room. I've been looking into using the `<canvas>` element but then I came across [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). This seems like the better way to go since it supports more browsers. The main things I will need from this interface is:

- Ability to control each side (any straight edge in the shape) and change the color of it.
- Save the positions of each shape so that I can reconstruct the layout any time.

The syntax for Raphael looks fairly simple, what would be the best way to store the SVG for each shape I make so that when the user clicks "Add" the shape is already calculated and can be added?

So basically, is Raphael a good choice for this type of interface/needs? And, how would I store information such as the shapes that I make, as well as each layout (combination of shapes, dimensions, and position of each shape) in a database so I can load any saved layout?

Comment: Personally, I would look in to jQuery UI and the `draggable` feature, coupled with floating `<div>`s you can use as furniture pieces. From there, you can scrape all layers placed and get their position, their size, etc. and use AJAX to store the information for later use, saving, etc.

Comment: @BradChristie I was actually just going to suggest a similar approach. If this application doesn't need to scale further than what's described here, you can probably get away with draggable divs. You can even use jQuery UI to force snapping to element edges, which would be handy for a layout tool.

Comment: So are you guys saying get rid of defining the shapes with SVG and go with images in `<div>`s?

Comment: I have to agree on the previous comments. Good Thoughts so far. To your question upon storage of the formulas: Maybe savein just within the JS as simple JS objects. You can break U- and L-shapes down to two/three rectangles, so the formula keeps simple, too.

Comment: The reason I chose to go SVG is because some of the non basic shapes have curves in them and I need a way to give a color to a side. There are 4 different colors and a shape could have up to 8 sides. So I need some easy way to draw that and store information about each side.

Comment: Well, I think part of your decision depends upon what the furniture objects will look like within your application. If you just want to represent solid, shaped blocks of color it might be easier to go with SVG or a canvas because you can quickly/easily offer new furniture options in the layout tool. If you are going to use textured, photo-like furniture representations, simply using images would probably be better. Either way, I think draggable divs will get you up and running the quickest--it's just a matter of what you put inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are in the right direction, keep with SVG and Raphael or you can use one of this libraries:

- **jsPlumb**: http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/ - provides a means for a developer to visually connect elements on their web pages. It uses SVG or Canvas in modern browsers, and VML for stone-age browsers. The latest version - 1.3.3 - can be used with jQuery, MooTools and YUI3. Full transparent support for dragging is included and the API is super simple.
- **JointJS**: www(dot)jointjs(dot)com/ - is a JavaScript library for creating diagrams. The diagrams can be fully interactive. Joint library is suitable for both implementing a diagramming tool as well as simply for publishing your diagrams. Features:
  connecting vector objects with various types of arrows; 
  interacting with connections and objects; 
  custom handlers for various events; 
  bent lines smoothing; 
  ready-to-use elements of well-known diagrams (ERD, Org chart, FSA, UML, PN, DEVS, LDM); 
  hierarchical diagrams; 
  serialization (to/from JSON format, SVG export only in browsers that support it); 
  extensible; 
  customizable;
- **Cajal**: http://dotsunited.github.com/cajal/ - cajal provides object oriented functionality to draw and animate shapes on the canvas element. You can easily reuse animations or complex shape-objects in other projects, as every shape can be assigned to as many canvas elements on your site as you like.

About the formulas, I would store the last dimensions and points in JS object format, I believe the formulas could be stored created in objects and using the strategy pattern you pass the correct one to be applied.

Comment: Thanks! The strategy pattern is a great idea, never would have thought of it. Question: so this works well on the client side but how would I store this on the server side? Say I have an L shape, it has 6 sides and I want to be able to store whatever dimension a user inputs for a given side. How do you represent that in a database? Would I create a "Shapes" table and a "Sides" table and a shape has many sides? Ideally a shape stored in the database would be able to be redrawn with the correct dimension for each side.

Comment: Well, I may think in 2 ways of doing it. 1) maybe the simpler but not so scalable is to save the serialized JS object itself, so you would have only one column to represent it, simplifiyng your persistence. Also simplifiyng the conversation throught layers. 2) You do persist the shapes in a complex way. This way you can represent the shape by points edges x1,y1 connected to x2,y2 ... Hope I've made myself clear. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to storing your objects and user-created layouts would be json & svg respectively.

Each piece of furniture could be a json object with properties for size, color, etc, a method for using those properties to generate a svg fragment, a method for getting the square-footage based on the properties, a reference to the svg element it represents, and setter methods that update the properties and the svg simultaneously.

The layout can be made in Raphael and the svg of the Raphael canvas saved as the layout state.
To store these all together in Mysql I would make one column for the svg state and one for a large json that contains all of the objects that are represented in the svg.

The downside is that the json is not very queryable. If that is needed, you may want to consider a native JSON database, such as MongoDB, as it will allow you to use the formulas of the objects in your queries.